# Can a child inherit both their parents' clans jutsu?

Tags: naruto

Can a child in Naruto inherit both abilities from his parents' clans?

For example, if Ino and Sasuke had a child is there a possibility for it to have both Uchiha's Sharingan and Yamanaka's mind transfer jutsu?

Comment: Yamanaka's mind transfer jutsu is something that is taught. It is a hidden ninjutsu. Sharingan is genetic, a kekkei genkai.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a child can inherit both clans' jutsu.

This was officially explained by Masashi Kishimoto(the creator of Naruto)
The child with an Uchicha and a Hyuga as parents will have both the clans' eyes.

While Inojin is not a good example as the techniques of his father Sai were taught to him.The Ninja art techniques are not passed via genetic inheritance.
Also, Ino's clan techniques are classified as Hidden techinques which use Yin/Yang release which are also taught/learned not passed via genetics.

A good example would be an Uchiha + Hyuga child as answered by Kishimoto himself -

[image: Interview with Kishimoto]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. And an example of it is given in Boruto.

In case you haven't watched Boruto yet,

> Inoijin, son of Ino and Sai possesses the ability to use both his parent's jutsus. Sarada can use Sharingan like her father Sasuke and has an awesome strength that she displays when she punches, just like her mother Sakura.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, sure.

In *Boruto*, Sarada has the Sharingan as his father's Sharingan and also possesses the monstrous strength his mother Sakura possesses. According to the manga, Shikadai is also said to possess both the jutsu as his father (Shikamaru) and mother (Temari).